# PHP | Storing boolean value in cookie

Tags: php, cookies, boolean

I have an issue. When I want to set Cookie with boolean(just false value) it doesn't store.

```
setcookie('myCookie',false);
```

even when I add expire time

```
setcookie('myCookie',false,time()+3600);
```

Notice: Undefined index: myCookie in C:\xampp\htdocs\Web\php\php_global_user.php on line 4

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Notice: Undefined variable and Notice: Undefined index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: no my problem is in storing FALSE in Cookie....

Comment: `on line 4` so where's the rest of your code? Plus, cookies only take effect on the 2nd page load.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cookies are plain text. When you cast a PHP boolean to text you only get sensible values with `true` because that's how PHP is designed:

```
var_dump((string)true, (string)false);
```

```
string(1) "1"
string(0) ""
```

Just use text from the beginning:

```
setcookie('myCookie', '0');
```

... or:

```
setcookie('myCookie', $value ? '1' : '0');
```

Comment: This is a very appropriate use of the ternary operator.

Answer (score 3):

Use 0 and 1 instead and change it back to boolean again then, when you load the cookie:

```
// set value to example variable
$setVar = true;

// setting the cookie
setcookie('myCookie', $setVar ? '1' : '0');

// reading the cookie
$readVar = isset($_COOKIE['myCookie']) && $_COOKIE['myCookie'] === '1';
```